# How to create immutable objects in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constants, immutability

Kotlin has a const-keyword. But I don't think constants in kotlin are what I think they are. It seems to very different to const in C++. It seems to me that its is only available for static members and to what are primitives in Java and do not compile for class-variables:

```
data class User(val name: String, val id: Int)

fun getUser(): User { return User("Alex", 1) }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    const val user = getUser()  // does not compile
    println("name = ${user.name}, id = ${user.id}")
    // or
    const val (name, id) = getUser()   // does not compile either
    println("name = $name, id = $id")
}
```

As this seems not to work, I think what i really want is a second class, that deletes the operations i don't want to support:

```
class ConstUser : User
{
    ConstUser(var name: String, val id: int) : base(name, id)
    { }
    /// Somehow delte the setters here?
}
```

The obvious downside to such a apprach is that I must not forget to change this class, in case i change `User`, something that looks very dangerous to me.

But I'm not sure how to do this. So the question is: How does one make immutable objects in ideomatic Kotlin?

Comment: `const` is not about immutability. It's a signal for compiler to replace usages of such property with raw value during compile time. Immutability is achieved by not exposing mutating accessors. Compare `Collection` and `MutableCollection` interfaces in Kotlin stdlib

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `const` modifier in Kotlin is used for [compile-time constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants). Immutability is done with a `val` keyword.

Kotlin has two types of properties: read-only `val` and mutable `var`. `val`s are equivalent to Java's `final`s (I don't know how this relates to `const` in C++, though) and properties or variables declared as such can't change their values once set:

```kotlin
data class User(val name: String, val id: Int)

val user = User("Alex", 1)

user.name = "John" // won't compile, `val` cannot be reassigned
user = User("John", 2) // won't compile, `val` cannot be reassigned
```

You don't have to hide or delete somehow any setters of `val` properties as such properties don't have setters.

Comment: Read-only properties are not necessarily immutable nor final. A read-only property can hold a mutable object: ```val list=mutableListOf(1,2,3) list.add(4)
print(list)//[1,2,3,4]```

Answer (score 0):

To add to jsamol's answer:

- For updating immutable objects, you can use copy() method.
  -- But beaware: It is just a shalow copy, semantically like the
  commented lines below.

```
data class Car(
    val make: String,
    val manufactured: ZonedDateTime,
    val color: String
) {
    fun repaint(newColor: String): Car 
         = copy(color = newColor)

    //fun repaint(newColor: String): Car 
    //   = Car(make = this.make, manufactured = this.manufactured, color = newColor)
}
```